# RxJava/Retrofit/RxAndroid Lag

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am experiencing significant lag when making network calls in the `onResume` method of my activity/fragment. As an example, when I finish an activity, and the previous activity has a network call within its `onResume` the app hangs for 3-4 seconds while the network request is made and the UI updates and then finally completes the transition back.

Many of my screens require data to be loaded when revisiting the page. For example, I have a list of orders and a child page to create/update an order. When returning to the list of orders I require the list to be updated.

To achieve this I’m doing the following

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    fetchOrders()
}

fun fetchOrders() {
      Observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?.map {
       //DO COMPUTATION AND UPDATE UI HERE
       }.subscribe()
}
```

I’m assuming that because I’m updating the UI on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread` I am experiencing the lag. I was wondering if there was something I am doing wrong and what I can do to increase the performance of this. I have tried changing threads however I need to do it on the main thread as this is the only place to make UI updates.

Comment: Attach your full code of `fetchOrders()` method.

Comment: by the time you observeOn the main thread, the data should be ready already. If you need to do computation, do that before switching to the main thread

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanks for the suggestion. Are you able to show me an example of what you mean as I’m. It sure where I’d do it.

Comment: @AbuNoman I will add it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be if your computations are pretty heavy. It might be better to make them in `Schedulers.computation()`:

```
observable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map {
        // do computations
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        // update ui
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a shot and see how it goes. I’ll report back. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to your code, it seems computation and updates UI operation are in `main thread`. You have a heavy task in `map` and it's running on the `main thread` because `observeOn` change the downstream and `subscribeOn` change the upstream and downstream both. In your case, `map` should be execute on `computation` or `io` thread. Looks like:

```
fetchDataObserveable()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map {
        // do computations
    }
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        // update ui
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I’ll try it out